# The setOnClickPendingIntent() does not work on existing widgets after device boots up

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget which is supposed to react on click/tap events, and it does work perfectly until I reboot the device/emulator.

After a reboot, I have to manually remove all the widget instances from the screen and re-add them to make them react on events again.

The code below is called both in the onEnabled()- and onUpdate()-methods. And I double checked that all lines of the code is executed in both methods during device startup.

```
public void doSetUpClickIntent( Context context )
{
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = UtilityClass.doCreateIntent( context );
 if ( pendingIntent != null )
 {
  ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class );
  AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
  int [] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
  for ( int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds )
  {
   RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget );
   views.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.widgetlayout, pendingIntent );
   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( appWidgetId, views );
  }
 }
}
```

I am at loss to find a cause. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.